# Proceed to the next row when selecting all the data using PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, wamp

Anyone can point me out on how make php mysql proceed to the next row of table?

Example, I got a table:

```
ID     First Name    Last Name
01     Testing       Testing
02     Testing1      Testing1
```

In order for me to display the first data, I will have use below code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM MyGuests WHERE ID = 01";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
}
}
```

Now, my question is, how can I automatically display the next row or the 02 and rest of the row after I have called ID 01? I believe there's a specific code I will have to use in order to do this. If not, kindly point me on the right way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Drop the `WHERE ID = 01";` and run your code. The `while` is the looping structure and will proceed to the next row(s) in a multi-record result set. If your column name is `First Name` then `$row['First Name']` would return that data. The column name must *match* the identifier in the row.

Comment: That won't work => `WHERE ID = 01` as @JayBlanchard said. You'll need to either do `WHERE ID = '01'` if your column is varchar and contains that value, or `WHERE ID = 1` if `1` is indeed the row's number. ID columns should be `int` and not varchar if that's what you're using now as the type.

Comment: *Yeah,* spaces in column names shouldn't be used as they present many potential issues. Underscores as word seperators are better. You can always echo those out with a concatenate.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Moving on *Sam*... ciao.